# Show $ ||A|| \le \gamma \iff \gamma^2I_q - A^HA \ge 0 \iff \gamma^2I_p - AA^H \ge 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, svd

trying to understand the topic of 'A minimal norm completion problem'. There's an exercise I'm not able to solve yet.

Let $A \in \mathbb C^{p\times q}$. Then,
$$ ||A|| \le \gamma \iff \gamma^2I_q - A^HA \ge 0\iff \gamma^2I_p - AA^H \ge 0 \quad (1)$$

I bet this is easily extracted from the inequalities that I proved in this exercise: (by using SVD of A)
$$ ||A|| \le 1 \iff I_q - A^HA \ge 0\iff I_p - AA^H \ge 0  \quad (2)$$

I'm not sure how can I generalize on $\gamma$, can anyone show me what I'm missing in order to satisify the inequalities in $(1)$?

Comment: The middle item ($\gamma^2I_q - A^HA$) is not an inequality; it's just an expression. Is there a typo here?

Comment: @JohnHughes You're right, I'm sorry for the typo. It should be $ \ge 0$

Comment: What norm is $\| \cdot \|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we know $\forall A\in\mathbb{C}^{p\times q}$:
$$
\Vert A\Vert\leq 1\iff I_q-A^HA\geq 0\iff I_p-AA^H\geq 0
$$
If $\Vert B\Vert \leq\gamma$, then $\Vert\gamma^{-1}B\Vert\leq 1$ and we can apply the above statement:
$$
\Vert \gamma^{-1}B\Vert\leq 1\iff I_q-(\gamma^{-1}B)^H(\gamma^{-1}B)\geq 0\iff I_p-(\gamma^{-1}B)(\gamma^{-1}B)^H\geq 0
$$
But every one of these respective statements is equivalent to the corresponding statement in
$$
\Vert B\Vert\leq \gamma\iff \gamma^2I_q-B^HB\geq 0\iff \gamma^2I_p-BB^H\geq 0
$$
Thus $(1)$ is indeed a direct consequence of $(2)$.

Comment: You mean $A$ instead of $B$ right? :)

Comment: The letter doesn't matter, however, the matrix that appears in the last two expressions is always the same matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much.